# Help with Cartesian products

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm given the cartesian products $(A \times B) \times (C \times D)$ and $A \times (B \times C) \times D$ Explain why they are not the same.  Then explain why they essentially are the same, by giving 1-1 correspondences between both and the set $\{(a,b,c,d) : a \in A \wedge b \in B \wedge c \in C \wedge d \in D\}$

I get how they aren't the same as in the first is one ordered pair is the set of the other ordered pair, while the second is like 3-tuples with the middle being an ordered pair.

Where I'm stumped is explaining how they are the same.

Any help?

Comment: Is $((a, b), (c, d)) \to (a, (b, c), d)$ not a bijection?

Comment: It might be a philosophical debate between the different of _the same_ and _equivalent_.

Comment: In categorical terms they are *the same up to isomorphisms*.

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right about why they are not equal.

As pointed out in the comments above, though, they are the same *for almost all intents and purposes*, because there is a natural bijection between them, given by $$\bigl\langle\langle a,b\rangle,\langle c,d\rangle\bigr\rangle\mapsto\bigl\langle a,\langle b,c\rangle,d\bigr\rangle.$$

In almost every setting beyond set-theoretic (in which they are not the same because they don't have the same elements), this natural bijection will ensure that they "behave" the same way (whether that is as topological products, vector spaces, or whatever else), so there is rarely a need to make any distinction between them.

Comment: Ah, I kind of get it now.  I didn't think of it that way.  Could you just elaborate a tad on how it is a natural bijection?  I just haven't really dived into bijections, 1-1s and ontos just yet.

Comment: It's "natural" in the sense that it's the first thing that most people would think to try (whether or not they actually try it), when looking for a one-to-one correspondence between the two sets. It's also "natural" in the sense that there is no need to convolute things a bunch to obtain a bijection. For example, there are bijections $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q,$ but they are highly non-trivial.